# How-to Write ChromeOS image to USB?

Tags: disk-image, google-chrome-os

I have downloaded the chrome os build by hexxeh but I am confused what to do next as the link to write it to the usb on the website no longer works so I need to find another way.

How can I do this?

I have downloaded build 4028 from the hexxeh website http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/

Comment: What exactly did you download.  Provide the filename.  Update the question.

Comment: Which is the link to 'write it to the usb'?

Comment: The windows image writer download

Comment: The link does work - http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/. `Downloads are now on Sourceforge only.` So, click 'sourceforge' and download

Comment: If it is a bootable iso you can format your stick as NTFS and extract the image to it. Worked for me with many windows discs.

Comment: It is a disk image file not an iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the "https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/" link offered on the page you linked (buried inside the "Windows" tutorial accordion pane) it does work, and it takes you to the "Image Writer for Windows" home page.

On this home page, right near the top it says the following:

> This project is currently being migrated to Sourceforge. Please be patient.
>
> Downloads are now on Sourceforge only.

Links to the new SourceForge [project site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) are provided right below that:

[image]

Head there to download it.

Comment: I have done this but now I am stuck as to how to run this on my windows 8.1 laptop (Booting from SD card) any help?

Comment: @Sam That is an entirely different question. Please [ask a new question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) instead of asking it in a comment. You can also mark *this* answer as answered by clicking the tick to the left of the answer

Comment: Questions are not allowed from my account any more :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows then use Windows Image Writer or [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) then select the Image file and select the USB device from the menu and Click on Write. After that you will be able to boot from **Chrome OS USB stick**

Comment: It ways CreateProcess failed; code 740 The requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: Right click on the Win32 Disk Imager and run as administrator. it will work